# Can't find command after setting PATH in fish

Tags: shell, environment-variables, fish

I'm struggling to add `/usr/local/bin` to my *PATH* so I can use *geckodriver*, which is located in `/usr/local/bin/geckodriver`. I tried the to add the following to my config.fish

```
set -U fish_user_paths /usr/local/bin
```

and also

```
set -gx PATH $PATH /usr/local/bin
```

both approaches don't seem to work. When I try to use *geckodriver* after restarting fish I get the error

```
Command 'geckodriver' is available in '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver'
geckodriver: command not found
```

which is weird because it seems to find it but can't execute it. Any solutions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: after you updated your config.fish, did you `source` it again?

Comment: First, I recommend not using `fish_user_path`. It tends to cause more problems than it solves. Stick with the `set -gx PATH` solution. Second, the `Command 'geckodriver' is available` is not from fish. It's presumably coming from the `geckodriver` command because you are missing some other prereq of that command. You can confirm that fish is finding the right program by typing `type geckodriver`.

Comment: Somehow after extracting `geckodriver` again and putting it in `/usr/local/bin` it works now. Your comment on missing some prereq pointed me to the solution though. So thanks!